Find the URL which opened the cordova application
I want to find the URL which opened the cordova application, without plugin.
My config.xml :
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="./application/activity/[@android:name='MainActivity']">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="mycompany.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</config-file>

It works. Now how do I find the URL/URI in my js files ?
I can't find anything in the documentation that refers to it.
I use cordova 12.
EDIT : My question is different because the other subject does not talk about retrieving the url in javascript using cordova.
Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: How to get full deeplink url from intent?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My question is different because the other subject does not talk about retrieving the url in javascript using cordova

Maybe check https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent
